# Use Wordpress Template in c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, templates

There are plenty of Wordpress template out there, most of them are well designed.

I like to know, is there a way to easy to use Wordpress template in c# project.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab a copy of the output HTML and the CSS of the WP site and apply/build your ASP.NET site around it. This is straightforward in itself. Where most people get confused is when there's a master page in the mix in ASPNET; however, this is not a problem. Just start (with the HTML produced by the WP site) by creating the main divs working from the outside-in, using the master page and then content areas in your pages. Master page(s) will generally contain display elements common to all or a subset of pages.

Comment: Thank you for this straightforward solution, I more like to change the template later if possible, just as easy as change template in wordpress. So I thought there might be some solution to "feed" wordpress templates.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing "out-of-the-box".

You will need to write your own converter if you wish to do this, though translating a single page shouldn't be too difficult.